# dnu restore error (Could not find part of a path..)

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations, dnx, entity-framework-core, dnu

Anyone attempt using entity framework-beta8 migrations? Everytime I run the dnx ef command I get the following

> "Error: . Please run dnu restore to generate a new lock file"

running dnu restore then gives the error

> Could not find a part of the path "c:\users\Username\ .dnx\packages\Owin\1.0.0\Owin.1.0.0.nupkg.sha512

Any idea what's going wrong?

**EDIT**

> Checking it now and the path on the C drive is 1.0 not 1.0.0..that seems to be part of the issue here. Not sure if it was the right thing to do but renaming the folders worked in the end

Comment: Try deleting everything in C:\Users\Username\.dnx\packages.

Make sure your dnvm is using the correct runtime version (`1.0.0-beta8`)

Then run `dnu restore`

Comment: I'm using the right version of dnx and as added in the edit, renaming the folders worked but I dont know if that's the right way to go about it

Comment: out of curiosity - why do you need Owin in ASP.NET 5 ? ASP.NET 5 does not need this package...

Comment: @pg0xC the strange thing is I don't even have the owin package installed. The situation is all over the place. I'm will go through the entire code later today and see where I might have made some mistakes

Comment: @Lutando  your suggestion turned out to be the best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Lutando's suggestion but got a command prompt error

> 'dnx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

If you get this, do the following:

```
dnvm upgrade
dnu restore
```

Then you should be back in business